# How can I structure my abstract classes

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, unity-game-engine, abstract

I'm writing a game and would like an opinion on my class hierarchy.

Currently I have an Character class, an AICharacter class and a KnightCharacter class.

Character holds things like Death() which all characters must facilitate, AICharacter overrides Death() with extra details for AI driven characters. KnightCharacter overrides Character stuff like handling of Shields(Only for Knights).

How can I elegantly allow my player to possess a KnightCharacter : Character and my AI to posses a KnightCharacter : AICharacter : Character?

I bascically want  to only implement the AICharacter when its being controlled by an AI.

Thanks

Comment: I would use an interface for AI... that way KnightCharacter is inheriting Character and when you need to code the AI class you make it implement the AI interface.

Comment: Same as Martin above, if AICharacter is an ability then it should be an interface. Inheritance is defined as subclass is topclass. Interface implementation is defined as Class can do interface. In your case, Knight is a Character that can do AIMovement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach that gives a lot of flexibility is to break your characters and objects down into various aspects, where each aspect is its own class. Some examples of aspects that an action or RPG character might have are Health, Mana, WearsEquipment, UsesItems, MobileObject, PhysicalRigidbody, MeleeAttackPerformer, RangedAttackPerformer, MagicAttackPerformer, PlayerControlledMobile, AIControlledMobile, and even things like AudioSource, etc, etc... Each of these classes would derive from a common base, e.g. AspectMixin or something like that.

If you treat each of these classes as Mix-ins, then you gain a lot of flexibility in creating new archetypes that have the aspects that make sense for that type of actor. This will allow, for example, monsters and players to share the fact that they have health, but have different classes for controlling them (AI-controls vs player-controls). Further, the Health aspect can be added to a stationary object (e.g. a barrel), to allow it to be affected by damage.

To achieve this, your archetype objects store a list of aspects mixins for that archetype. Further, the aspects need to be able to query the main object for other aspects by type (or interface). It's a bit of work to set up, but that's the price of flexibility.

FWIW, this is the approach that the Unity Engine tries to encourage (consider they call them MonoBehavior: behavior..aspect...different words for the same concept), though many developers don't "get it" until they've made several failed prototypes in which classes quickly become monolithic.

---

To go back to your original question, it sort of depends on how many playable classes you have, and whether AI can control characters of the same classes. If so, it would best to abstract the Controls out of the characters, then have AIControls and PlayerControls derive from Controls, either of which is able to interface with your character class.

On the other hand if AI types can be broken into just a few various behaviors (aggressive monsters, peaceful NPCs), I would make each one an aspect.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. So for example I would have a Health aspect which would have a function SubtractHealth() and in that function I could do a check like if (GetComponent<AIController>() != null) // do AI only stuff.

I'm also not sure what the benefit of everything inheriting from a AspectMixin class, why not just add my components as MonoBehaviours?

Comment: Your health class shouldn’t care whether it’s controlled by AI or not. That behaviour belongs in the AI class that uses the heath class.

Comment: Looks like you're using Unity. Good. Makes this easier. So I suggest having Health have some Add() and Remove() methods, basically everything any other class would need to interface with the health module. Your AI Controller loads a reference to Health in Awake() typically, and then uses it as necessary. E.g. if (myHealth.CurrentHPPercentage < LOW_HEALTH) { DrinkHealthPotion (); } or Flee, or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking isn't possible with ordinary c# inheritance.  Your brother can't have a different grandfather from you.

Since you seem to be looking for ideas, here's one that uses generics:

```
abstract class BaseController
{
    virtual GameEvent ReadNextEvent();
}

class PlayerController : BaseController
{
    override GameEvent ReadNextEvent
    {
        return userInterface.ReadNextEvent();
    }
}

class NonPlayerController : BaseController
{
    override GameEvent ReadNextEvent
    {
        artificialIntelligenceEngine.Think();
        return artificialIntelligenceEngine.ReadNextEvent();
    }
}

abstract class Character<T> where T : BaseController
{
    protected T controller;

    abstract ProcessEvents();
}

class KnightCharacter<T> : Character<T>
{
    override ProcessEvents()
    {
        var e = controller.ReadNextEvent();
        switch (e.Action)
        {
            1 : SwingSword(); break;
            2 : LiftShield(); break;
            3 : Yell("None shall pass!"); break;
        }
    }
}



class Program 
{
    void Example()
    {
        var playerKnight = new KnightCharacter<PlayerController>();
        var aiKnight = new KnightCharacter<NonPlayerController>();
    }
}
```

Comment: The method here is the right answer for single inheritance (when you need only need features from a single-inheritance chain of classes). Once you need features from multiple base classes, you would need to move to Composition or reimplement code for various Interfaces since Multiple Inheritance isn't supported. Common practice seems to be  composing mix-ins, as I described in my answer.